# React Refs - using refs as a raw data container

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Could Refs be "legally" used as a raw data container? No DOM manipulation.
Suppose that I have function component and I want to store only one object that will persist across function calls all the time. Can I use refs to achieve this or there is a different approach?

```html
 const settingsStorage = useRef(new SettingsLocalStorage());
```

After ref creation I just refer to its .current property

```html
const current = settingsStorage.current
```

And I also modify .current property

```html
settingsStorage.current = new...
```

Comment: yes you can do it . The idea of ref is to have a value preserved for the entire component lifecyle and also mutate it without triggering a re-render .

Comment: Thank you, I just wanted to make sure. Always I see refs in context of direct DOM manipulation.